# Is it possible to prevent matlab from defining variables which overwrite function names?

Tags: matlab, built-in, reserved-words, redefine

From time to time I have this problem with Matlab where I for example, create a variable named "max" and then get all kinds of weird errors when I try to use the function max() on something, since I overwrote the function by accident with my variable.

I have lost much time and my mind, and I find it awful that this is even possible.

I would like to know if there is a way to disable this behavior, so that function names are reserved like in many other languages and this cannot happen by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html), you can't do that.

You should use `exist <name>` when in doubt to make sure that `<name>` won't override an existing function.